Visual Studio cannot find installed .NET 8.0
I'm using Windows.Devices.Bluetooth in my .NET 8.0 WPF application and VS Code seemingly can't find the libraries this references. In my .csproj file, I have
<TargetFramework>net8.0-windows</TargetFramework>

and I noticed that if I change it to the specific version I have installed on my machine, ie net8.0-windows10.0.22621.0, the error goes away.
My question is: how can I have VS Code find the this without forcing the app to use a specific build of the framework? It's annoying because I don't want the users to have to download this specific build when another will work perfectly fine.

The types in Windows.Devices.Bluetooth are provided by Windows itself, not by .NET. If you look e.g. here, "Windows requirements", you'll see it needs Windows version 10.0.15063.0 (i.e. 22H2) or above. So yes, you need to target that Windows version or above in your csproj. That's saying that you need a particular minimum version of Windows, not .NET. Note that this is a minimum bound: everyone with version 10.0.22621.0 or above is fine.

What error? can't find the libraries that doesn't mean VS can't see the .NET 8 SDK, provided it's installed. if I change it to the specific version ... the error goes away perhaps because those Windows SDK libraries only exist after a specific OS version?

Okay I'm not sure what's going on. I'm in the TargetFramework property : why does changing this not affect the framework I'm targeting setting the minimum compatible Windows version ? Isn't there a TargetOS property or something like this that could do this ?

That is the attribute that can do this, and already does. You said so yourself: the error goes away. If you use the correct minimum target platform, the build works. You aren't specifying a Framework version, you're specifying a platform version. In .NET 6 and later, net8.0-windows10.0.22621.0 specifies both the SDK and the platform-specific SDK.  What you seem to be looking for is how things worked before .NET 5 , where you'd specify win-x64, win10-x64 etc separately from netcore3.1. To get that to work though you had to add the platform-specific packages yourself.

A TargetFramework of net8.0-windows10.0.22621.0 means ".NET 8.0 (or later) running on Windows 10.0.22621.0 (or later)"

You're using vscode for wpf development? Why?

VS means Visual Studio.
